# Laravel "project_name/public" is removed from URL when i add sub domain in route group

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3

I am trying to add sub domin for specific routes like this :

**web.php:**

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'subdomain.domain.com'], function() {
  Route::GET('login', ['as' => 'login.index', 'uses' => 'LoginController@index']);
});
```

the problem in the url it becomes like this **"subdomain.domain.com/login"**
it must be like this **"subdomain.domain.com/projectname/public/login"**

**project_name/public** is removed when i add domain in route group, this happens in **local environment**

Comment: `/public` shouldn't be in the URL, that's the project root, your domain should point to this directory

Comment: i am in the local environment , i know this won't happen in the production , how can i fix this local?

Comment: What's the issue of not having **projectname/public** in your URL ?